# Why does this code work on Windows 7, but doesn't on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, listview

A little background: I'm a WPF to WinForms convertee and for some time I've been migrating my application.

I was reported by a friend that my code doesn't work on Windows XP (it generates a stack overflow at startup) even though it works fine on Windows 7 (which I develop in).

After a little research, what caused the problem was something along these lines:

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
     listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
 }
```

Now that I noticed the obviously poor decision, I wasn't wondering why it doesn't work on Windows XP. I was wondering *why does it work on Windows 7*.

Obviously at some point the compiler figures out what I'm trying to do and prevents the same event to be fired over and over again, but **I'd much rather have it do nothing, so I can see and squish the bug on sight on the platform I'm developing in, rather than have to test it under two platforms simultaneously.** Back in WPF I could handle such behaviour manually by setting e.Handled to 'true', in WinForms apparently there's no such thing.

Is there some sort of a compiler flag for this?

Comment: You'll have to roll your own flag AFAIK

Comment: I have never heard of any one migrating from WPF -> WinForms! FairPlay.

Comment: What version of .NET are you running against? There are some bugs in 4.0 fixed by installing 4.5 on W7, but you can't do the same on XP. (I doubt this is it but you never know.)

Comment: Why on earth would someone go *from* WPF to Winforms?

Comment: I'm developing in 4.0. This is precisely because 4.5 is not available on XP.

Comment: Why are you setting selected inside a selection event? That's probably why it gets into a stack overflow you'll need to add better checking (i.e if not the item you want selected then do selection otherwise ignore).

Comment: Be aware, then, that _you can no longer be sure how your code will run on XP_. There are documented bugs in 4.0 fixed by upgrading to 4.5, and even by building against 4.0 your Windows 7 machine will no longer exhibit those bugs. (I still doubt this is the issue here, but the more you know...)

Comment: @Killercam lol I took 2 years to migrate from WinForms to WPF its so damn complicated but you know progress bars in comboboxes make it so cool

Comment: Ah, yeah. Being able to put anything into anything is certainly a trait. :) However, this time I need a more native solution, and I'm also hoping to be able to port it to Mono.

Comment: @kuraj that explains it ;) but its not supported anymore from win8 so you need to make 2 versions now (what is also very smart)

Comment: What? It runs on Windows 8 just fine.

Comment: @Kuraj yes it runs but its not supported, like XP its still available but it isn't supported anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!listView1.Items[0].Selected) {
       listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
       listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
   }
}
```

You only want to SET selection ONCE, on your first item. The problem is it's likely getting into a perpetual loop.

As to why Windows 7 is more forgiving than XP I couldn't say. Could be the order the LVM_* messages are processed in or anything.

Comment: Yeh but adding/removing the events is a bit expensive/extreme :)

Comment: I know but its something new for much people and I didn't thought it of that way

Comment: I guess this workaround is as straight-forward as you can get :) That said, I already knew why the bug occured. I was only worried about the different behaviour part.

Answer (score 2):

Check and see if the .NET version makes any difference. If you have a newer version of .NET on your Windows 7 machine than on XP (very likely), then it is possible for there to be differences even if you are targeting the earlier version.

See what [MSDN says about .NET backwards compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

this may work (NOT TESTED)

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) listview1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
   listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
   listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
   if(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) listview1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

edit look its OS specific :o

Comment: Haha. This makes the XP one behave just like the 7 one did, but now the 7 one behaves even more differently. What exactly is the deal here... :)